# UWP AdaptiveGrivew horizontalAligment not working

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp

I creat app UWP and using AdaptiveGridView of Mircosoft.Toolkit but when i create my ToggleButton in AdaptiveGridView not in center. How i can fix it?

[image: This is problem]

My Code

```
<Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ToggleButtonTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="a" Content="{Binding Textttt}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        MinWidth="150" Click="Button_Click" 
                        Style="{StaticResource HeinekenToggleButtonStyle}"
                        />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
<Page.Resources>
<controls:AdaptiveGridView Name="MenuItemGrid" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   Margin="5"
                                   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ToggleButtonTemplate}"
                                   Grid.Row="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Row** and **Column** definitions and then set **Grid.Column="0"** and **Grid.Row="0"** for ToggleButton like this:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/><RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/><ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ToggleButton x:Name="a" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Textttt}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    MinWidth="150" Click="Button_Click" Style="{StaticResource  HeinekenToggleButtonStyle}"
     />
</Grid>
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: It's not working. I just want  item in adaptiveGridvew horizontal center. But horizontal not working, i don't understand.

Comment: I think ToggleButtons are centered in its parent Grid But for AdaptiveGridView  , Which version of toolkit is installed? refer to this old fix for this problem [AdaptiveGridView HorizontalAlignment not working after version 2.0.0](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/1737) 
Also did you tested it by replacing AdaptiveGridView with standard GridView ?

Comment: i use version 5.0.0. I have read your link but i don't understand and i don't see how to fix it

Comment: I have a try with GridView but it does not work either

Comment: If you are using ver5.0 no problem , Its an old thread and fixed already.

Comment: try to put entire AdaptiveFridView in a Grid then set `HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"` for both Controls (instead of VerticalAlignment="Top").

Comment: hi @DMT, the  `HorizontalAlignment` is used to make the whole `GridView` horizontal center. not for each items. if you want to make the last two items horizontal center  you could refer this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46521221/7254781)

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected. At first I thought what is wrong at all looking at the picture. At the end I realize that you want the last two items to be centered in the last row instead of displaying them from the start.

In theory it is possible, but there is no operating system in existence with controls that would work like that as far as I know (and I've built applications for all major operating systems). So you have to build everything from the scratch if you really want that, you can't rely on any control as simply this isn't considered as a good design.

Horizontal alignment means of how your control is placed inside its container, not how the container is placed inside its row, there is no property that would affect that.