# How to put GridView on a multiple row/column Grid?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a `GridView`(each contains a image and a text), which uses `DataTemplate`. And my Grid is divided into 30 `grid-rows` and 40 `grid-columns` via codes like below. I attached a picture to show my case, please check it.

```
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
<RowDefinition Height="*" />

<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
```

There is total 25 `GridView` items (`image + text` for each), depends on the binding data. And I need to put these 25 items onto 3 rows, e.g. each item will occupy 5 `grid-rows` and 4 `grid-columns`.

My question is:

（1）how to specify location of each `GridView` item?
Below code will make all the GridView items occupy the whole App Layout, but do not make it align as I want.

（2）The whole layout should support scroll horizontally. That is, when swipe the layout to left, the new icons(image+text) hidden on the right side will be shown.
How to achieve it?

```
   <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Skills}" 
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
              ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SkillDataTemplate}"
              Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="30" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="40"
              >
    </GridView>
```

[image]

Comment: could you make a graphic to explain it ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT  I attached a picture to show my case, please check it.

Comment: Set GridView item margin could not approach ?

Comment: For re-layout GridView item this reply may [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46489443/center-aligning-gridview-items-in-last-row/46521221#46521221).